# Not able to ssh from VM to VM via linux bridge

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, bridge

I want to able to ssh from VM1 to VM2, both VM are connected to a Linux bridge(br0). Below is my topology

```
VM1(m1)<====SSH====>[br0]<======SSH=====>VM2(m2)
```

## 1 Created bridge br0

```
$ sudo ip link add dev br0 type bridge
$ sudo ip addr add 10.200.1.1/24 dev br0
$ sudo ip link set br0 up
$ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

## 2 Specified bridge name while launching VM

[image]

```
veeru@ghost:~$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br0     8000.fe540005c7df   no      vnet0
                            vnet1
docker0     8000.024205ca1927   no      
virbr0      8000.5254003bf832   yes     virbr0-nic
```

I can see the network is UP in guest VMs and **ABLE to ssh from host to guest without any problem.**

But when I try to do ssh from VM1(m1) to VM2(m2), VM2 is not reachable. I have checked with tcpdump in VM2(m2) that ssh packet are not reaching from VM1(m1). **But I can ping from VM1 to VM2.**

Seems like I'm missing some points about linux briding concepts

## PS:

I also try to add my wifi interface(wlp0s20f3) to linux bridge, but

```
sudo ip link set wlp0s20f3 down
sudo ip link set br0 down
sudo brctl addif br0 wlp0s20f3
can't add wlp0s20f3 to bridge br0: Operation not supported
```

I have not touched iptables in guest as well as host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables
>  net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables
>  net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables
> ```
>
> These control whether or not packets traversing the bridge are sent to
>   iptables for processing. In the case of using bridges to connect
>   virtual machines to the network, generally such processing is *not*
>   desired, as it results in guest traffic being blocked due to host
>   iptables rules that only account for the host itself, and not for the
>   guests.

So, disable bridge-nf parameters like below. This should work.

```
sudo sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables=0
sudo sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables=0
sudo sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0
```

Can find more info @ [libvirt blog](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Net.bridge.bridge-nf-call_and_sysctl.conf) and [linux foundation blog](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/bridge)